# Abort an insert from a before_insert event in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm adding automatic validation to one of my models in a pyramid application with [before_insert](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.before_insert).

So far I've got this:

```
def Property_before_insert_listener(mapper, connection, target):
    formvalidator =  PropertySchema()
    try:
        return formvalidator.to_python(target.__table__.columns)
    except formencode.Invalid as error:
        print ("***************************************ERROR" + str(error))


event.listen(
    Property, 'before_insert', Property_before_insert_listener)
```

Everything seems to be working fine, and I get the proper error printed out in the console.  However, after handling the error, it continues with the insert. How do I stop the insert from happening?

Answer (score 1):

In the sqlAlquemy documentation for [Mapper Events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#mapper-events) you have something that might help you:

> **retval=False**
>
> when True, the user-defined event function must have a return value, the purpose of which is either to control subsequent event propagation, or to otherwise alter the operation in progress by the mapper. Possible return > values are:
>
> - `sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces.EXT_CONTINUE` - continue event processing normally.
> - `sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces.EXT_STOP` - cancel all subsequent event handlers in the chain.
> - other values - the return value specified by specific listeners.

Comment: This does not seem to work with the `before_insert` event in particular.